# Does $A\overset{\exists!f}{\to}B\overset{\exists!g}{\to}C\Rightarrow A\overset{\exists!h=g\circ f}{\to} C$?

Tags: category-theory

To prove that two coproducts $P_1,P_2$ of $A,B$ are isomorphic one uses that $\exists!f:P_1\to P_2$, $\exists!g:P_2\to P_1$ somehow means that $\exists!h=g\circ f:P_1\to P_1$ (see [this](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Category_Theory/Products_and_Coproducts#Definition) for the proof). However I don't understand why this is true. In general I don't see why the following holds (and I actually don't think it is true):
$$A\overset{\exists!f}{\to}B\overset{\exists!g}{\to}C\Rightarrow A\overset{\exists!h=g\circ f}{\to} C$$

The reason I find this dubious is because not every map $h:A\to C$ has to arise at a composition of maps $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to C$. However, this is the result which seems to be used implicitly in the proof of the coproducts being isomorphic.

Any help in clearly this up would be much appreciated.

Comment: The point is that there is a unique map $P_1 \to P_1$ making the appropriate diagram commute (because $P_1$ is a coproduct). Now $g \circ f$ is such a map and $1_{P_1}$ is such a map, so they must be equal.

Comment: You can have other arrows from $A$ to $C$ but there is only one composition of $f$ and $g$.

Comment: @Magdiragdag Ah of course! I feel pretty dumb now:p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that just because there is exactly one map $A\to B$ and exactly one map $B\to C$ does not imply there is only one map from $A\to C$.  However, that is not what is being used in the argument you're referring to.  Rather, there is a unique map $P_1\to P_1$ because $P_1$ is a coproduct (here you are taking $X=P_1$ in the definition of a coproduct).

(Here, as in the question, "unique map" means "unique map which commutes with the specified maps from $A$ and $B$".)

Comment: Thank you, I totally missed that we would get a new diagram with $X=P_1$...